# Getting incorrect output from HTML form using $_POST method

Tags: php, html, forms

I was having trouble with getting my login form to redirect to user home page since last night, after one successful attempt. After filling the form, I would press submit but I remained on the same page, except the form would be cleared. 
So i decided to echo my inputs using the $_POST method, and after resubmitting the form, I saw that the page displayed **1** for both the entries. What is wrong in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php require_once("../Includes/Session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../Includes/DB_Connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../Includes/Functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../Includes/Validation_Functions.php"); ?>

<head> 

<title> eTransport: Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Login_Style.css">
</head>

<html> 
<body>
<div class="div1">
    <h1 class="title"> Online eTransport Service (Fiji) </h1>

    <div>
    <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
        eTransport_ID: <input type="text" name="eTransport_ID"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit"><br>
        <?php echo isset($_POST['eTransport_ID']); ?><br>
        <?php echo isset($_POST['Password']); ?>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$id = isset($_POST['eTransport_ID']);
$password = isset($_POST['Password']);

$checked_id= mysql_prep($id);

$query = "SELECT eTransport_ID ,Password FROM etrans_id_details";

$login_set = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_set)){
    if ($checked_id == $row["eTransport_ID"] AND $password == $row["Password"]){
        redirect_to("Home.php");
    }
}

?>
```

The Output for my Code with $_POST:

[image: img]

Comment: You're storing the result of `isset` in `$id` and `$password` -- not the actual ID and password

Comment: it's displaying 1 because that you're using isset().  1 = true in that sense.  The variables are set.

Comment: Have a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: I only added isset() since the browser gave 2 errors under the form as undefined index. how do I remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the long answer.
Replace 

`$id = isset($_POST['eTransport_ID']);
$password = isset($_POST['Password']);`

with

`$id = $_POST['eTransport_ID'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];`

and add code to test if it is set.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but upon reloading the Login page, it displays 2 errors saying undefined index. How do I remmove that?

Comment: you need to put test to see if the variable is set so `if ($id == '') die(0);` and one for the other.